# Comparing fixed intercepts of different mixed models R

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, intercept

Given 3 variables: y is continuous, x is continuous, z is a repeated measures factor, nested within subjects. I have two models from different data sets a and b:

```r
fitm1 <- lme(y ~ x + z, random = ~1|subject/z, data = a)

fitm2 <- lme(y ~ x + z, random = ~1|subject/z, data = b)
```

Is there a way to compare the fixed intercept of m1 to the fixed intercept of m2 in terms of significance testing? So far I have just found ways to compare complete models to each other using `anova()`.

Comment: 1) combine the data. 2) fit a single model with related interactions terms. 3) test if the two intercepts are equal.